# node.js - FREE-ing res.end() - from a asynchronous call - function

Tags: node.js

i want to move

```
res.end();
```

right above the

```
  }).listen(80);
```

that way i can have only one `res.end();`
for the entire script.. rather than multiple..

currently this is my script:

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '-------------',
    user     : '2',
    password : '-------------',
    database : '1',
});

connection.connect();


var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
        var oo = require('/3.js');
        oo(connection, function (e, result) {
        res.end(result);
        });

}).listen(80);
```

i do not know how to free

```
 res.end(result);
```

so that it can be placed right above the

```
 }).listen(80);
```

and thus become more logical.
( logical because : suppose `aa` will be a variable that could come from different sources. ) ( eg: "if" "else"..)

i tried:

```
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});

     var oo = require('/3.js');
     oo(connection, function (e, result) {
     var aa = result;
     });

res.end(aa);

}).listen(80);
```

without success.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [express framework](http://expressjs.com/), which will make it much easier to make different routes call different parts of your code.